# What does let NAME1 = NAME2( params ) { var1, var2 in mean in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am new to Swift and some constructs I can't even read. For example:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
```

What is it? Function call because of `()`? Or inline anonymous class declaration because of `{}`? Or enumeration because of `in`?

Comment: You should read the Swift Programming Language (SPL) or you'll have a hard time. Although a lot is similar to C#, it's the definitive place to answer "what is this construct?" questions https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html

Comment: There are plenty of nice answers here but here is another quick tip: think of the last part as the anonymous inline version of `func handler(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) {...}`

Answer (score 1):

That is trailing closure syntax. `URLSession.dataTask(with:)` returns a `URLSessionDataTask` instance and its last input argument is a closure of type `(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void`, where the async network request response or an error is returned.

You can use the `URLSessionDataTask` object to call start or cancel the network request.

If you don't use trailing closure syntax, it might be more clear what you're seeing:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
    // you can use data, response and error inside the closure here
})
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
```

The trailing closure syntax simply allows use to omit the input argument label for the last input argument when it is a closure and put the closure with the curly brackets after the closing parentheses of the function call.

Comment: ***object to call start or cancel the network request.*** you meant **resume or cancel** as well as **state**

Comment: @LeoDabus even though the function is called `resume` in reality it starts the request, so I did mean start, not resume.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift this is called a completion handler. It's basically an anonymous function that you pass in which the function you are calling will call when it's done. In Swift this can either be written as a normal parameter or as a closure after the function call, which is what is happening in your example.

You can see in the function definition from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1407613-datatask)

```
func dataTask(with request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionDataTask
```

That there are two parameters to the function `request` and `completionHandler`

In Swift, when the final parameter is a function it can be, and often is, written as a closure after the function call.

NOTE:
As was suggested in another comment, this is **NOT** the return value. You'll see this function has a return value of `URLSessionDataTask` which is being assigned to `task` in your example